# Replace a range of values in an SQL table to a single value

Tags: sql, replace

I am trying to replace a range of values with a string. I know how to do it with the replace function but that, as far as I know, requires them to be done one at a time.

Is there a way to select a range of values, for example (1-200), and replace them with a singular string value say "BLANK"?

I have tried WHEN, THEN and SET but get a syntax error near WHEN or SET as I try these.

Base Code Idea

```
Select DATA
WHEN DATA >= 1 THEN 'BLANK'
WHEN DATA <200 THEN 'BLANK
END
FROM DATABANK
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results. What is the datatype of `data`?

Comment: And what database are you using?

Comment: This is for an SQL database named DATABANK, the data is simply a set of integers in the range of 1-200. I want to replace them with either 0 or the string "BLANK"

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select data,
    case when data not between 1 and 200 then data end as new_data
from databank
```

What this does is take the integer value of `data`, and replace any value that's in the 1-200 range with `null` values, while leaving other values unchanged. The result goes into column `new_data`.

The assumption here is that `data` is a number - so the alternative value has to be consistent with that datatype (string `'BLANK'` isn't): I went for `null`, which is consistent with any datatype, and is the default value returned by a `case` expression when no branch matches.

If you wanted something else, say `0`, you would do:

```
select data,
    case when data between 1 and 200 then 0 else data end as new_data
from databank
```